# Was this scene in Deadpool a reference or nod to the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

During the climactic scene of *Deadpool*, our eponymous hero travels to a new location

> in order to face down Ajax and rescue Vanessa.

The setting of the scene looked quite familiar,

> like it was one of the damaged helicarriers of S.H.I.E.L.D., possibly from the events in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*.

Is there any source, official or otherwise (press publication, Twitter status, blog post, etc.), to indicate whether or not that's what it really is? Since *Deadpool* is part of the X-Men Cinematic Universe, is it even allowed to have such a reference (if officially acknowledged anywhere)?

This is not asking where the Amix Group got/came into possession of the carrier, like the linked duplicate below.

Comment: Was this scene in Deadpool a reference-

Yes. The answer is always yes.

Comment: @ibid That's asking a different question (how did group X acquire this object) based on some incorrect assumptions. We know those assumptions are incorrect due to the answer, but better yet, due to *this* question and answer set. Regardless, that question was asked a week after mine, so really it should be closed as a dupe of mine, if they were the same question.

Comment: @TylerH - Different questions, but overlapping answers. I vtc this one because I felt the other one has more extensive answers.

Comment: @ibid I don't think including more of a quote really counts where it matters as "more extensive".

Comment: @TylerH - The other question has answers with direct quotes from producers and involves a lot more of the in-universe history. It's answers do a good job answering both questions. The one short answer posted here doesn't.

Comment: @ibid Have you looked at the answer below? It provides direct quotes from the writer of the script and provides background to their original desires and their ultimate outcome. The effective difference is your answer on the target quotes more words.

Comment: @TylerH - The only answer I see posted below contains three paraphrased sentences and a link to an interview. No direct quotes, "no background to thier original desires and their ultimate outcome".

Comment: The movie tag is not to be used just to say “I’m asking about a movie” that is implicit with the movie tag.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Care you revise your argument? You accidentally supported my point. The movie tag's meaning is implicit in the movie tag?

Comment: With the movie [work] tag. Sorry on my phone so didn’t realise I missed a word.

Comment: I won’t roll back the edit of the tag again to avoid an edit war but I will say that is ___not___ how the tag should be used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They didn't have the rights.

> “We wanted the carrier to be a Helicarrier,” said Reese of the concluding fight scene’s setting, “but we couldn’t get the rights to that, so it was just a regular old kind of aircraft carrier.”
>
> <sub>[Flickering Myth, Exclusive: Deadpool “couldn’t get the rights” to Avengers joke](https://www.flickeringmyth.com/2016/02/exclusive-deadpool-couldnt-get-the-rights-to-avengers-joke/)</sub>

Comment: The article's title says it was for a joke. What was the joke?

Comment: The carrier probably was the joke, seeing that it shouldn't be there since its from another universe