# How did Amix Group get this helicarrier?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

In Deadpool,

> A big fight scene takes place in a battered helicarrier at an Amix Group scrap yard.

What is the history of this particular helicarrier? And why in particular was it sent to the Amix Group scrap yard?

Comment: Pretty sure it has no connection to the MCU. IIRC there are interviews where the producers say that it isn't known as a "helecarrier".

Comment: I'm guessing that ought to be "Ajax's group" and auto-correct is involved.

Comment: I just figured it was a big ship. Didn't realize it was supposed to be a helicarrier.

Comment: @AnkitSharma http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120376/what-is-amix-group

Comment: @ibid: there’s apparently [a podcast interview with the movie’s writers](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/119502/440) where they claim that they *wanted* it to be a downed Helicarrier, but they couldn’t get permission.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You forgot that, I have also answered it :D

Comment: @AnkitSharma: oh yeah!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It was decommissioned and sold for scrap, it's not a helicarrier, and it never belonged to S.H.I.E.L.D.**

Quoting from  ScreenRant's on set interviews with the Director and Writers:

**It was decommissioned and sold for scrap**

> What happens is in Act 3, Ajax, our villain, is trying to soften Deadpool up for the kill, so to speak. So he lures Deadpool out to this scrapyard, essentially. **And among the things in the scrapyard is an old kind of beat up, decommissioned helicarrier.** So it’s sitting there and it becomes a big set piece, part of the fight, this massive fight between Colossus, and Angel Dust, and Negasonic, and Ajax, and Deadpool, and a ton of thugs. So it’s just a great playground.
>   But this is like the twisted dark side of the helicarrier we’re used to seeing. It’s not gleaming, and shiny, and cool, and flying through the air. **It’s been sold for scrap**, essentially.
>   <sub>[(*source - ScreenRant's on-set interview with the Writers*)](http://screenrant.com/deadpool-interview-rhett-reese-paul-wernick/2/)</sub>

**It's not a helicarrier, and it never belonged to S.H.I.E.L.D.**

> **It’s clearly not a helicarrier…** [Laughs] … Because that would violate the Marvel S.H.I.E.L.D. universe sort of thing. [...] **to be fair, there are Helicarrier-like vehicles in the X-Men universe. It’s not just S.H.I.E.L.D. that has them.** So I think it’s fair game.
>   So I think the more we can bring that world into his world the better. But it has to be done in such a way that it feels Deadpool. So, what better way to do it than a decrepit carrier that’s being stripped for scrap? And it’s dirty, and grungy, and nasty. When you see the shots that are up on the flight deck of that ship, **it’s obviously not up to S.H.I.E.L.D. spec in its design.** It looks more like a World War 2 sort of technology with… some… turbo fans.
>   <sub>[(*source - ScreenRant's on-set interview with the Director*)](http://screenrant.com/deadpool-director-tim-miller-interview-set-visit/2/)</sub>

Comment: of course, the most obvious reading of Miller's comment is "duh, of course it's a Helicarrier ,but we can't actually *say* that because we'd get in trouble, so ... uhh.. nope. no helicarrier here!"

Answer (score 2):

In the original script, there wasn't a helicarrier at all. It was a tall building.

The old aircraft carrier was actually another building which was the setting for a massive – and very violent – gunfight which goes on for pages and pages in the screenplay. That scene also ends with Deadpool using the bodies to spell out “FRANCIS” when he’s done.

But due to budget cut (or some other reason) they changed the scene to take place in the helicarrier. If you want to find more about the difference between the original script and the movie script, take a look at [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/120088/62088).

My assumption of why they wanted use a helicarrier is they wanted to make a connection between this movie and other MCU movies that use helicarriers.

*What is Amix Group?*

Comment: I had thought they did it to make a tenuous connection as well. But my theory goes a step further in that it's the helicarrier from Avengers prior to Project Theta.

Comment: There is a sign at the entry point to the scrap yard.  The sign says "Amix Group."

Comment: @CodeMed Honestly didn't realize that.

Comment: I've read through interveiwer where the producers insisted that it wasn't actually a "helicarrier", just an airship that exactly resembled one. (More of a comic reference than an MCU reference.)

Comment: @ibid As a Marvel comics and MCU fan, I couldn't catch the difference whether if it was a helicarrier or not. It might be a reference to both of them. Deadpool's target audience is highly based on fans like me (us). It wouldn't be surprising if one sees the thing as a helicarrier and some other see it as something else.

Comment: @apollo - Well WoG is that it isn't an MCU helicarrier.

Comment: @ibid That's the entire point. They say it's not but they still prefer to use something that will evoke the opposite.

Comment: @apollo - I believe the OP wanted an in-universe answer.

Comment: @ibid You give your answer, I give mine. It is so convenient that they use a helicarrier instead of a building. They could use something else but chose to use one particular vehicle. And then they _explain_ it the way they did in your answer to deny that they do such thing. Simply *marvelous*.