# What is Amix Group?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

In Deadpool,

> a big fight scene occurs at a scrap yard where there is a large vessel that looks like a helicarrier.

The sign at the entrance to the scrap yard says "Amix Group".

What is Amix Group? Is this company mentioned in other Marvel stories, like Stark Industries or Pym Technologies? Or is it a private reference made up by one of the writers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amix Group is a real life Canadian company, its details can be checked on its website: http://amixgroup.ca/.

There is no Amix Group in Marvel comics as per my knowledge. It might be some kind of intentional/unintentional product placement, nothing else.

Comment: Thank you and +1.  Funny how we assume things like that are fictional. They may simply have been filming at an Amix facility because it was a realistic setting.

Comment: omg it actually turned out to be a product placement.