# How can Deadpool the movie make direct reference to mutants?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

With *Deadpool* being an MCU movie, how can it make direct references to mutants and Xavier's Mansion when the previous Avengers movie, *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, couldn't? Likewise in *Agents of Shield* they have created Inhumans instead of mutants.

Comment: Deadpool is known with 4th wall phenomenon in Marvel. He was simply making funny references to other X-Men.

Comment: “Deadpool being an MCU movie” — sure. Disney made a superhero movie with anal sex references.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Disney has made R-rated movies before: e.g. *Down and out in Beverly Hills*

Comment: @OrangeDog: “R-rated” means a lot more in America than it does in reality, but I think Disney distributed that movie, as opposed to having a great deal of influence over the creative process.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Disney's relationship with Marvel Studios isn't significantly different than with Touchstone. If anything, they have more official control over the latter. Anyway, a moot point.

Comment: When did deadpool became MCU film?

Comment: I mistook Marvel Entertainment with Marvel Studios.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*Deadpool* is not an MCU (Earth-19999) movie. It is an XCU (Earth-10005/TRN414) movie.

It is produced by 20th Century Fox, who own the film rights to the X-Men, Marvel mutants in general, and the character Deadpool.

Comment: okay, yes, its a Fox movie......Not Marvel Studios......thanks.

Comment: As a side note, that's why they couldn't explicitly reference the last battle being on a SHIELD helicarrier, since they did not have the rights to that.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots is referencing [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/118425/13024) btw.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, *Deadpool* is a Fox Live Action Studios production meaning ***Mutants*** and ***Xaviers School*** are fair use.

The **Brand** 'Mutant' was sold to Fox along with characters from the MU comics. This means *Marvel can't refer to Mutants* and *Fox can't refer to Avengers*.

Rumours are circulating that Fox is going to sell its MU properties back to Marvel Studios which would help to clear up a lot of the confusion regarding what is canon and especially when it comes to overlapping or shared characters with differing timelines.

Comment: But they can refer to Helicarriers for some reason...

Answer (score -6):

At all times that Deadpool is around, movie or otherwise, the fourth-wall is rendered invisible. I've read that part of his insanity in the comics is actually because *he knows he's a fictional character*.

So him referencing things that may not be in the same universe is part of the humor (like gags that are supposed to cause you to wonder 'how did *blank* do/know *blank*?').

Comment: Deadpool is not immune to the real world force known as "lawyers". It has nothing to do with the character, it's all about the studio and legal control of the intellectual property.

Comment: @T.J.L. Ah, I thought they were asking why Deadpool knew about the other movies. My mistake; I apologize.